# Supporting Controllers on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, controllers

I'm currently developing a small, cross-platform game for Windows/OSX. I have XInput support working correctly on the Windows version. I've left off Mac controller support until now and I'm struggling to find an analogous library on OS X.

Does something similar to the XInput API exist for OS X or am I on my own for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking into this as well and I have yet to find something as clean and simple as XInput on the Mac. A library that's commonly recommended is [OIS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wgois/) but it seems like it's not being maintained anymore.

You can also take a look at the game pad implementation in [SFML](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/tree/master/src/SFML/Window/OSX). It has game pad support for Windows, Mac and Linux. I haven't gotten a chance to take the SFML game pad stuff for a test drive yet but I've been impressed with SFML in general.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Dave Dribin's DDHidLib library for all of my controller support lately. It's an Objective-C wrapper around IOHIDLib. I also comes with a few sample projects to get you started.

- [About DDHidLib](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2007/03/19/ddhidlib_10/)
- [Google Code Project](http://code.google.com/p/ddribin/downloads/detail?name=DDHidLib-1.1.tgz)

"Included is DDHidDevice, a class for generic HID devices, as well as four subclasses for common device types: joysticks (and gamepads), mice, keyboards, and the Apple IR remote. DDHidDevice provides easy access to HID elements and queues. The subclasses provide easier access to device specific elements (i.e. you don't have to dig through recursive dictionaries to find the mouse buttons), and provide delegates for asynchronous notifications of these elements."