# Gamepad support for OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

What is the most common method for providing gamepad support in an OS X game? I've been using an IOHIDLIB wrapper named DDHIDLib https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDHidLib and it seems to be working but I find it odd that there isn't something more recent.

Comment: Latest OSXs have a PS3 controller driver built into the OS. I tested it with glut and sfml. All the buttons and axes worked fine. Not sure about rumble and sensors though.

Comment: I had a quick look at SFML's input code, its using apple's framework IOKit for the PS3 Controller. So you should be fine with that, no need for 3rd party drivers/libs. Just use apple's IOKit's HID interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45691/supporting-controllers-on-mac?rq=1